# Where can I find a list of button icons available for JQGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

You can change the icon for a button in JQGrid using the `buttonicon` property. Do you know where I can find a comprehensive list of the different types of buttons that are loaded with the grid? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These icons come from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) project. Check out [Theme gallery](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) for all available icons.

http://tinyurl.com/9dutmtl

Comment: One can use also http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.23/tests/static/icons.html or [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.23/tests/static/icons.html)

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ This information is available in JQUERY UI Documentation page